# Area routing in asp.net core 6

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a `.net mvc core 6` application with the following area on it `Dashboard`

I added the following configuration to `Configure` in `startup`

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                name: "Dashboard",
                areaName: "Dashboard",
                pattern: "D/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
            // other areas configurations goes here 
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "areas",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
              );
        });
    }
```

the above code works fine to identify each area route and it will work like this `http://localhost/d/dashboard` will redirect to `Dashboard` area the issue is on how to use this with the normal routing of the mvc like

```
   Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "d" })
```

this will generate the following link `https://localhost/Dashboard?area=d` not `http://localhost/d/dashboard` even when changing the code to be like this

```
   Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "Dashboard" })
```

this will generate the following link `https://localhost/Dashboard?area=Dashboard` not `http://localhost/d/dashboard`

Any help with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for @Chen after multiple retries I found the issue

- Removed the `endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();` from my code.
- Added the default route for the controller to be like this

  ```
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
              );`
  ```
- Change my routes in action link to be like this `@Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard", new { Area = "dashboard" })` instaed of `Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "d" })`

so the final code in my `startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // Rest of the code

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
            name: "Dashboard",
            areaName: "Dashboard",
            pattern: "D/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );

        // other areas configurations go here 

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
              );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();` to the end.

Matches from a route that appears earlier have a higher priority. Conventional routing is order-dependent. In general, routes with areas should be placed earlier as they're more specific than routes without an area.

Your routing order takes precedence using `MapDefaultControllerRoute()`. When redirecting, it defaults to passing Area as a parameter.

For more details, you can refer to [this official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#conventional-routing-order).

Comment: It's still not working. I will check the link you posted